# Suppose $G_1, G_2 \leq G$ where $G_1, G_2$ are abelian. Do the elements of $G_1$ and $G_2$ commute with each other?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G_1$ and $G_2$ are abelian subgroups of $G$.  Does that also mean that an arbitrary element of $G_1$ commutes with an arbitrary element of $G_2$?

i.e for $g_1 \in G_1$ and $g_2 \in G_2$ $g_1 g_2 = g_2 g_1$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Simply consider a nonabelian group $G$, two non-commuting elements from this group and the groups that are generated by these elements.

Comment: but how do we know nonabelian groups exist?

Answer (score 1):

What happens in $S_3$ with $G_1=\{1,(12)\}$ and $G_2=\{1,(13)\}$?